# How to create Mongoose schema for 3 users i,e Admin Manager and Employee?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, mongoose-schema

i am working on MERN STACK app..
i want to create 3 users schema i,e Admin employee and manager pease help me out how create that 3 users schema

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can do this with only 1 schema. You can define field named "role" in your user schema and everytime user login you can validate that role and check if the role is "admin" ,"employee" or "manager".

Comment: roles: {
        type: [{
            type: String,
            enum: ['admin','manager','employee']
        }],
        default: ['employee']
    },

Answer (score 0):

You can use this schema on your auth schema.

```
role: {
        type: String,
        default: "user",
        enum: [
            "admin",
            "employee",
            "manager"
        ]
    }
```